# how to get id of each image generated within ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the below html, i'm trying to display a table which consists of 8 cells
.Each cell displays an image, onClicking on image it call changeImage function which gets the image id and changes the image.

```js
//But its changing only one cell's image.When i click on image of any cell in table only first cell's image is changing.I know it is because of  id="myImage" declared in img tag.I'm trying to generate Seperate Id for each image but unable to do so.
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
    image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
  } else {
    image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="bottom">
  <table id="t01" ng-if="Obj.Element">
    <tr>
      <th>hello</th>
      <th ng-repeat=" ElementObj in Obj.Element"> {{ElementObj.a.b}}</th </tr>
      <tr>
        <div class="tooltip">
          <th>{{Obj.c}}</th>
          <span class="tooltiptext">{{Obj.d}}</span>
        </div>

        <th ng-repeat="  ElementObj in Obj.Element">
          <div>
            <img id="myImage"  ng-click="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Objective : When i click on individual cells of table it should change the image. i'm trying to display a table which consists of 8 cells.Each cell displays an image, onClicking on image it call changeImage function which gets the image id and changes the image.

Comment: Why do you use `onClick` in an Angularjs application? You should use the `ngClick` directive. And there's rarely any reason to query elements from the DOM in Angularjs

Comment: How your ElementObj looks like?

Comment: You just need to review your codes and use model to handle it, please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have `src` or `id` to handle change image, because you already have a model and you can change model instead element.

default we set `src` by `ng-init` and then we change it in our controller, as this sample:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.elements = [{
      title: "A"
    },
    {
      title: "B"
    }
  ]

  $scope.changeImage = function(element) {
    var a = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQizZdER3przCQLcVB5b66j02wFyNRXxYIoYXIjqyntm2tpjIRA";
    var b = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    element.src = element.srcType ? a : b;
    element.srcType = !element.srcType;
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th ng-repeat="element in elements"> {{element.title}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="element in elements">
          <div ng-init="element.src = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';element.srcType=true">
            <img ng-click="changeImage(element)" ng-src="{{element.src}}">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have need pass dynamic id for image so print $index value in id attribute after pass this 
as param in  function that will help you to change image of current image.

```
    <img id="myImage"  onclick="changeImage(this)" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

function changeImage (e) {
  e.src = "PASS YOUR IMAGE PATH";
}
```

Comment: can u elaborate

Comment: That' can easily be posted as a comment, and even then it would not be helpful one. @rajnikanthsabnekar - You can change `ng-click="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif"` with something like `ng-click="ElementObj.bulbon = !ElementObj.bulbon" ng-src="{{ ElementObj.bulbon ? 'pic_bulbon.gif' : 'pic_bulboff.gif' }}"`

Comment: @Alon Eitan actualy i anwered by phone so there i was geting problem in editing properly.

Comment: NP, so please try and improve it with more details when you get to your computer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same `id` for a set of element since the id should be unique in the page.

I suggest you to use the event property since it contains already the target element you clicked:

```
<th ng-repeat="ElementObj in Obj.Element">
    <div>
        <img id="myImage" ng-click="changeImage($event)" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

    </div>
</th>
```

And then in your JS:

```
function changeImage(event) {
    var image = event.target;
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
```

Ref.: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-

Answer (score 0):

```
<th ng-repeat="  ElementObj in Obj.Element">
          <div>
            <img id="myImage{{$index}}"  ng-click="changeImage('myImage' + $index)" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

          </div>
        </th>
```